# Adding annotations through java Youtube API

Tags: java, youtube, youtube-api

I have uploaded few videos using the youtube api and would like to add annotations to those videos.

Is there a way to add the annotations for the youtube videos using the Youtube API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a full feature support in the API yet, but you can use invideoPromotion for taking it to different videos, external sites etc.

http://apiblog.youtube.com/2013/10/spice-up-your-channel-with-invideo.html

Comment: Thanks. Will try to use the "Invideo Promotion" for my case

Answer (score 0):

Anand.

If you want to change the video Description or a tag associated with the video or other data, I believe that you can use the solution provided at this sample of API;

[youtube/api-samples](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/java/src/main/java/com/google/api/services/samples/youtube/cmdline/data/UpdateVideo.java)

If you want to change the description, call the method:

```
snippet.setDescription("new desc").
```

Before the execute() method :

```
YouTube.Videos.Update updateVideosRequest = youtube.videos().update("snippet", video);
        Video videoResponse = updateVideosRequest.execute();
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hi, May be I was not clear. What I would like is, to add annotation for the video.. Is there any specific api for adding the annotations?

Comment: Hi, may I ask what kind of annotations? The video tags and description aren't fitting your requirement? by the way, the video object of the google api are represented by a formmatted json [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos), I don´t see other holes there that would accommodate more custom texts, like your "annotations". Perhaps store it in your local db and associates it with the youtube videoId be the only way.

Comment: Hi, It would be something like having the a link on the video ("click here for similar videos") which would take you to an external site.

Comment: It seems that you are referring to those little balloons that appear when running the video. At the moment it seems that few functions of this kind are available trough the "InvideoProgramming" (like watermarks) and these seem to be bind only to the Channel object and not to the Video object. You can follow this request for more details about ....  [link](https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=558)

Comment: Thanks. Will try to use it